# How many squares, cubes, fourth powers, etc. do I need to sum to n?

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, number-theory

You are given a nonnegative integer `n` and an integer `p >= 2`. You need to add some `p`-th powers (`p=2` means squares, `p=3` means cubes) together to get `n`. This is always for any nonnegative `n`, but you don't know many `p`-th powers (of any **positive** integer) you'll need.

This is your task: find the minimum number of `p`-th powers that can sum to `n`.

**Examples**

```
>>> min_powers(7, 2)
4                       # you need at least four squares to add to 7
                        # Example: (2)^2 + (1)^2 + (1)^2 + (1)^2 = 4 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7
>>> min_powers(4, 2)
1                       # you need at least one square to add to 4
                        # Example: (2)^2 = 4
>>> min_powers(7, 3)
7                       # you need at least seven cubes to add to 7
                        # Example: 7*(1)^3 = 7
>>> min_powers(23, 3)
9                       # you need at least nine cubes to add to 23
                        # Example: 2*(2)^3 + 7*(1)^2 = 2*8 + 7*1 = 23
```

A related Wikipedia article on this problem, [Waring's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring's_problem).

**Rules**

- Your code *must* be a program or a function.
- Input is two integers `n` and `p` in any order. You can assume all inputs are valid (`n` is any positive integer, `p >= 2`
- Output is an integer representing the number of powers needed to sum to `n`.
- This is code golf, so **the shortest program** wins., not necessarily the most efficient.
- Any and all built-ins are allowed.

As always, if the problem is unclear, please let me know. Good luck and good golfing!

Comment: Well, it looks like brute force will win. I hope not though.

Comment: This problem is __incredibly__ hard, and I doubt that any answer will either ever finish while giving correct results.

Comment: At least have upper bounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

*Saved [1 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/65473/how-many-squares-cubes-fourth-powers-etc-do-i-need-to-sum-to-n/65489?noredirect=1#comment158523_65489) thanks to FryAmTheEggman.*

```
L&bhSmhy-b^dQS@bQyE
```

Takes input on two lines, `p` first and then `n`.

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%26bhSmhy-b%5EdQS%40bQyE&input=3%0A23&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%26bhSmhy-b%5EdQS%40bQyE&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A7%0A2%0A4%0A3%0A7%0A3%0A23&debug=0&input_size=2)

#### Explanation

The code defines a recursive function `y(b)` that returns the result for `min_powers(b, p)`.

```
L                      define a function y(b):
 &b                      return b if it's 0
             S           get a list of positive integers less than or equal to
              @bQ        the p:th root of b
     m                   map the integers to:
        -b                 subtract from b
          ^dQ              the p:th power of the current integer
       y                   recurse on the above
      h                    increment the result
    hS                   find the smallest result number and return it
                 yE    calculate y(n) and print
```

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica <s>61</s> 50 bytes

With 11 bytes saved by LegionMammal978.

When restricted to powers of counting numbers, this problem is straightforward (in Mathematica).  When extended to include powers of integers, it's a nightmare.

```
(k=0;While[PowersRepresentations[#,++k,#2]=={}];k)&
```

---

**Test Cases**

```
(k = 0; While[PowersRepresentations[#, ++k, #2] == {}]; k) &[7, 2]
(k = 0; While[PowersRepresentations[#, ++k, #2] == {}]; k) &[4, 2]
(k = 0; While[PowersRepresentations[#, ++k, #2] == {}]; k) &[7, 3]
(k = 0; While[PowersRepresentations[#, ++k, #2] == {}]; k) &[23, 3]
```

> 4
>
> 1
>
> 7
>
> 9

---

`PowersRepresentationsp[n,k,p]` finds all the cases in which `n` can be expressed as a sum of `k` positive integers raised to the `p`-th power.

---

For example,

```
PowersRepresentations[1729, 2, 3]
```

> {{1, 12}, {9, 10}}

Checking,

```
1^3 + 12^3
```

> 1729

---

```
9^3 + 10^3
```

> 1729

Comment: Competitively languages like Mathematica defeat the purpose of these things... it doesn't take any creativity to know a function name.  But still, well written.

Comment: @csga5000 Hey, golfing languages win 99% of the challenges on this site...

Comment: @LegionMammal978 While I don't agree with csga's point, golfing things down in golfing languages requires a *huge* amount of creativity.

Comment: Agreed, no awards for creativity on this submission. Nor for compactness: the Pyth submission is less than half the length.  Problems become challenging for languages like Mathematica when they can be recast as instances of more general phenomena and when unusual combinations of high-level functions can play a role.  They also become more interesting.

Answer (score 3):

### Java - <strike>183</strike> 177 bytes

```
int p(int a,int b){int P,c,t,l=P=t=a,f=0;double p;while(P>0){a=t=l;c=0;while(t>0){if(a-(p=Math.pow(t,b))>=0&&t<=P){while((a-=p)>=0)c++;a+=p;}t--;}f=c<f||f==0?c:f;P--;}return f;}
```

---

**183 bytes**

```
int p(int a,int b){int P,c,t,l,f=0;P=t=l=a;double p;while(P>0){a=t=l;c=0;while(t>0){if(a-(p=Math.pow(t,b))>=0&&t<=P){while((a-=p)>=0){c++;}a+=p;}t--;}f=c<f||f==0?c:f;P--;}return f;}
```

### Ungolfed

```
int p(int a, int b){
    int P,c,t,l=P=t=a,f=0;
    double p;
    while (P>0){
        a=t=l;
        c=0;
        while (t>0){
            if (a-(p=Math.pow(t, b))>=0 && t<=P){
                while((a-=p)>=0)c++;
                a+=p;
            }
            t--;
        }
        f=c<f||f==0?c:f;
        P--;
    }
    return f;
}
```

---

### Result

```
System.out.println(p(7, 2));    // 4
System.out.println(p(4,2));     // 1
System.out.println(p(7,3));     // 7
System.out.println(p(23,3));    // 9
```

Comment: This answer is invalid. `p(32,2)` returns `5` when it should return `2` (`4^2 + 4^2 = 32`).

Comment: @Pietu1998 Ok I'll modify it.

Comment: @Pietu1998 How would you do it?

Comment: I did it recursively, checking each possible power for every number.

Comment: @Pietu1998 I'll try it thank you;

Comment: @Pietu1998 Got it, it works now, thanks again.

Comment: @YassinHajaj +1 for java and doing it yourself

Comment: @csga5000 thx man :)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 66 bytes

```
f=lambda n,p:n and-~min(f(n-k**p,p)for k in range(1,n+1)if n/k**p)
```

Recursively tries subtracting each `p`-th power which leaves the remainder non-negative, computing its value on each remainder, and taking the minimum  plus 1. On 0, outputs 0.

The ugly check `if n/k**p` (equivalent to `if k**p<=n`) is to stop the function from going into the negatives and trying to take the `min` of the empty list. If Python has `min([])=infinity`, this wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Wow. This is a *lot* shorter than my test code on Python. +1!

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 122 bytes

```c
r(n,p,k,s,j,b){if(!k)return n!=s;for(b=j=1;j<n;b*=r(n,p,~-k,s+(int)pow(j++,p)));n=b;}f(n,p,k){for(k=0;r(n,p,++k,0););n=k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzNDoIwEAbvPgVoSHbtkiiYeKi98hRe5KeGFldSNB4IPrq1wGX2sN9Mld6rynsHTD1ZGshQiWOrIbbomtfbccSxGqR@OiiVUUdpLizLvVqNbxocAS2/sH9@wAhBPSJKVqWc9BrFcZatOsjVEcLSAeU8snLyu7rRLTdRMT@xd6GlYashqSlKaoxU4JW3NKtLMeQ3j1vLgGMBZ8qwgNPCM@WBWR7O5H@V7m73wafd4w8)